# Is it possible for l3keys' key to contain a \long value?

Tags: expl3, l3keys

In the following MCE, the `key` key (of `.tl_set:N` type) stores a `⟨value⟩` which is added, centered, at the end of the document. It works well, except if the `⟨value⟩` is `\long` (is multi-paragraphs).

Okay, `interface3.pdf` says page 5:

> TeXnically, functions with no arguments are `\long` while token list variables are not.

Is it possible for `l3keys`' key to contain a `\long` `⟨value⟩`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn { mymodule }
{
  key .tl_set:N = \l__mymodule_tl
}
\DeclareDocumentCommand \MyModuleSetup { m }
{
  \keys_set:nn { mymodule } { #1 }
  \AddToHook{enddocument}{%
    \begin{center}
      \l__mymodule_tl
    \end{center}
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\MyModuleSetup{
  key = { That's all     folks! },
  % key = { That's all\par folks! },
}
\begin{document}
Once upon a time, ...
\end{document}
```

Comment: the problem is that the argument of your setup command is not long, use `+m`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Indeed, it was so obvious! :) But suppose I'd like some keys, the values of which to possibly be `\long`, and some other keys, the values of which to _impossibly_ be `\long`. Wouldn't it be possible to decide this at the `\keys_define`'s level?